# Format date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library to format dates in the format **MM DD, YYYY**. What am I missing?

Code below:

```
import moment from 'moment';

var dateStr = '2015-10-19T13:33:52.140Z';

var d = new Date(dateStr); // Mon Oct 19 2015 13:33:52 GMT+0000 (GMT)

console.log( moment(d, "MM DD, YYYY").toDate() ) // Still outputs Mon Oct 19 2015 13:33:52 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need tou use JavaScript `Date` to parse your string, just use [`moment(string)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) (because your input is in ISO 8001 format), then you have to use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```js
var dateStr = '2015-10-19T13:33:52.140Z';
console.log( moment(dateStr).format("MM DD, YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Simply use the Format method

```
moment(dateStr).format("MM DD, YYYY");
```